How to find the complete USB information for a USB device under Python3 and Windows
Story behind:
I am currently learning Python3 privately. I am still at the beginning and already have problems with the first simple project. And sorry for my lousy code - I am a beginner.
Goal:
List all removable USB devices (SD card reader) in a Windows environment (not Linux) with all parameters, like drive letter, physical address, file system, VID, PID, ... (see code below, drive_dict).
Problems:

the VendorID (VID) and ProductID (PID) are not correct or 'None'
I cannot query the write protection of the SD card (slider on the left side) under Windows. I am looking for an equivalent to 'os.statvfs(drive_path)', which according to the docu is only available for Linux.
if multiple USB card readers are connected no VID or PID is returned.

import ctypes
import libusb
import os
import psutil
import wmi


# --------------------------------------------------------------------- windows equivalent of linux 'lsusb'
def get_usb_detail(all_usb_dev, level, usb_addr):
    desc = libusb.device_descriptor()
    libusb.get_device_descriptor(all_usb_dev, ctypes.byref(desc))
    description = "{:04X}:{:04X}".format(desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct)
    # print(f'\n... description (vend, prod ID) : {description}')
    # ----------------------------------------------------- bus
    bus = libusb.get_bus_number(all_usb_dev)
    # print(f'... get_usb_detail | bus ; {bus}')
    # ----------------------------------------------------- address
    address = libusb.get_device_address(all_usb_dev)
    # print(f'... get_usb_detail | address ; {address}')
    # ----------------------------------------------------- path
    buffer = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 7)()
    pointer = ctypes.cast(ctypes.addressof(buffer), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
    n = libusb.get_port_numbers(all_usb_dev, pointer, 7)
    path = '-'.join([str(i) for i in buffer[:n]])
    # print(f'... get_usb_detail | path ; {path}')
    # ----------------------------------------------------- output like Linux 'lsusb'
    print("Bus {:d},\tDevice {:d},\tID {},\tPath {}".format(bus, address, description, path))
    # ----------------------------------------------------- idVendor and idProduct
    # >>>> is following compare correct?? - I don't think so
    # result of Nirsoft USBDriveLog: Loacation: Integrated : Bus 0 : Device 0 : Function 8 : Adapter 0 : Port 0
    #                                DiskNumber: 3, Vendor ID: 0bda, Product ID: 0169
    print(f'... compare address = {address} with usb_addr = {usb_addr}')

    if address == usb_addr:
        idVendor = "0x%04X" % desc.idVendor
        idProduct = "0x%04X" % desc.idProduct
        return idVendor, idProduct

    return 'None', 'None'


def get_usb_list(usb_addr):
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------- check libusb for windows
    r = libusb.init(None)
    if r < 0:
        print(f'*** error {r}: can\'t initalize libusb')
        return r
    try:
        devs = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(libusb.device))()
        cnt = libusb.get_device_list(None, ctypes.byref(devs))

        if cnt < 0:
            print(f'*** error {cnt}: no USB devices found')
            return cnt

        for i in range(cnt):
            idVendor, idProduct = get_usb_detail(devs[i], 0, usb_addr)  # Calls function: get_usb_detail
            if idVendor != 'None' and idProduct != 'None':
                return idVendor, idProduct

        libusb.free_device_list(devs, 1)
    finally:
        libusb.exit(None)

    return idVendor, idProduct


# --------------------------------------------------------- get_removable_drives
def get_removable_drives():
    usb_devices = []
    c = wmi.WMI()
    for drive in c.Win32_DiskDrive():
        if drive.MediaType and 'Removable' in drive.MediaType:
            # print(f'::: drive : {drive}')
            for partition in drive.associators("Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"):
                # print('+++ get_removable_drives|partition ', partition)
                for logical_disk in partition.associators("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
                    # print(f'... get_removable_drives|logical disk = {logical_disk}')
                    volume_label = logical_disk.VolumeName if logical_disk.VolumeName else None
                    try:
                        sd_serial = os.stat(logical_disk.DeviceID).st_dev
                    except PermissionError:
                        sd_serial = None
                    # --------------------------------------------------------- drive info
                    drive_info = psutil.disk_usage(logical_disk.DeviceID)
                    # --- get DiskIndex instead of physical_drive
                    usb_addr = partition.DiskIndex
                    disk_index = str(partition.DiskIndex).zfill(4)
                    physical_drive = drive.Name
                    drive_letter = logical_disk.Caption + '\\'
                    print(f'\n... usb_addr = {usb_addr}')
                    print(f'... diskIndex = {disk_index}')
                    print(f'--- phys drive = {physical_drive}')
                    print(f'::: drive letter = {drive_letter}')
                    usb_disk = partition.Caption.split()[1][:-1].zfill(4)
                    usb_part = partition.Caption.split()[3].zfill(4)
                    print(f'... partition.Caption : {partition.Caption}')
                    print(f'... usb_disk = {usb_disk}')
                    print(f'... usb_part = {usb_part}\n')
                    # --------------------------------------------------------- idVendor and idProduct using usb_addr
                    idVendor, idProduct = get_usb_list(usb_addr)
                    print(f'... dev_vendor_id = {idVendor}')
                    print(f'... dev_product_id = {idProduct}')

                    # --------------------------------------------------------- unresolved / troubles | start
                    # there is only a solution for Linux using 'attributes = os.statvfs(drive_path)'
                    is_write_protected = False  # dummy value for system satisfaction
                    # --------------------------------------------------------- unresolved / troubles | end

                    # ------------------------------------- create dict
                    drive_dict = {'dev_vendor_id': idVendor, 'dev_product_id': idProduct, 'dev_removable': True,
                                  'is_write_procetcted': is_write_protected, 'disk_index': partition.DiskIndex,
                                  'volume_label': volume_label, 'volume_serial_number': logical_disk.VolumeSerialNumber[
                                                                                        0:4] + '-' +
                                                                                        logical_disk.VolumeSerialNumber[
                                                                                                     4:8],
                                  'sd_size': drive.Size, 'sd_serial': sd_serial, 'drive_letter': logical_disk.Caption,
                                  'physical_drive': physical_drive, 'file_system': logical_disk.FileSystem,
                                  'total_size': drive_info.total, 'used_space': drive_info.used,
                                  'free_space': drive_info.free, 'percent_free': drive_info.percent}
                    usb_devices.append(drive_dict)
    return usb_devices


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # vendor_id = 0x0bda, product_id = 0x0169       NoName CardReader
    # Bus 1,    Device 3,   ID 0BDA:0169,   Path 7

    # vendor_id = 0x11b0, product_id = 0x6368       Kingston CardReader

    usb_devices = get_removable_drives()
    print(f'\n\n... list of result dict(s) : {usb_devices}')
    print(f'... # of usb devices found : {len(usb_devices)}')

    if len(usb_devices) > 0:
        print(f'... VendorID : {usb_devices[0]['dev_vendor_id']} | expected: 0x0bda')type here

It is also possible that my approach is completely wrong. Unfortunately I don't know the command set of Python3 well enough yet. Maybe someone can solve this with a one-liner :-))
I am working on Python 3.12.2, Windows 10, PyUSB, Windows binaries libusb-1.0.27.7z
